# Flashing code to device from Visual Studio + visualGDB

Tags: visual-studio, stm32, visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio Community 2015 and visualGDB and building an embedded application for STM32. Every tutorial only shows how to debug the project, but is it possible to flash the code to the device as it is possible form other IDEs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - In your project settings under "Debug Method", you will set your Programming interface. (In my case I am using an STM32F072 Discovery board, with its integrated ST-Link V2 interface.) This same interface is used for both programming and debugging.

When you start a debug session, it will compile your code, flash your device, and then start executing in debug mode. You can also just "run" the program, which will build and flash your code and execute it without debugging.

Either way, the program will remain on your device, so for an individual hobby project you can "deploy" after a successful debug/run session if you want.

If you want to flash multiple devices without building every time (i.e., for production), I'm not sure if there is an option for that. It might be better to just use the ST-Link utility outside of Visual Studio/VisualGDB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look for stLink tool provided by ST. Take a look on 'visualGDB StLink and openOCD'